# OSX Python3.6: Installing and linking GDAL

Tags: macos, python-3.x, gdal

I am having issues linking gdal with Python3.

I have successfully installed gdal using homebrew, where I get the following responses in terminal:

```
$ gdal-config --version
2.1.3
$ ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
```

However in Python3, on trying to import osgeo (or gdal) I am getting:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

I have tried installing gdal using pip3, however the following error is returned:

```
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Any ideas on how to sort this out?

Thanks!